# Difference between Bitangent and Binormal

Tags: geometry

I have come across `bitangent` and `binormal` being used interchangeably in my workspace to refer to what is actually a `binormal` by definition.

My understanding is that `bitangent` implies a line that is tangent to two points on a curve. Does `bitangnet` also imply a different thing?

I am curious if it is acceptable to use them interchangeably.

What confuses me more is that I see a similar usage in this answer as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2843724/1650417

It would be great if you can clarify if the terms could be used interchangeably.

Comment: It can also mean [bitangent vector](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BitangentVector.html) to a surface in computer graphics. But [binormal vector](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinormalVector.html) is to a curve, so it is hard to see how they can be used interchangeably unless one uses some special curves on the surface binormals to which are the bitangents.

Comment: "In the field of computer graphics, two orthogonal vectors tangent to a surface are frequently referred to as tangent and binormal vectors. However, for a surface, the two vectors are more properly called tangent and bitangent vectors."
So, bitangent is more appropriate in the case of surfaces, right, although both the terms are acceptable?

Comment: So says Wolfram. I suppose it is because bitangent is orthogonal to both the normal and the chosen "first" tangent, which, if it was a curve with that tangent and principal normal (but isn't), would produce the binormal. If you foliate the surface by a family of geodesics (so that their principal normals are normal to the surface) their binormals would be the bitangents.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The links and your explanation about the terms cleared it up for me. We have curves on 3d meshes in our program. So, they seem to be switching between these terms based on the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, from the discourse in the comments, I am now clear that the Binormal is generally used for curves. In the case of surfaces, the vector perpendicular to the normal and the first tangent is called a Bitangent. Specifically, if the surface is foliated with geodesics Binormals to these geodesics are in fact Bitangents.